# Android - Split text in columns

Tags: android, split, textview

I should split a long text for being shown within as much column as needed. For instance i've got a 80 lines text and i want to show it within two textview longer then larger one next to the other one, each one with a maxlines of 60. Any suggestions for doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but even though ...
maybe have a look here :
http://www.accella.net/multi-column-text-displays-in-android/

you need to display your text into a first textview, then get what does not appear in that first textview, then display it in a second textview and so on.
To get the "invisible" text from your textview, here is some code:

```
private String getInvisibleText(final TextView textView) {
    String invisible = null;
    int height    = textView.getHeight();
    int scrollY   = textView.getScrollY();
    Layout staticLayout = textView.getLayout();

    int lastVisibleLineNumber  = staticLayout.getLineForVertical(scrollY+height);
    int start = staticLayout.getLineEnd(lastVisibleLineNumber);
    int end = staticLayout.getLineEnd(textView.getLineCount()-1);

    if (textView.getText().toString() != null
            && !textView.getText().toString().isEmpty() 
            && end > 0
            && textView.getText().toString().length() >= end) {
        invisible = textView.getText().toString().substring(start, end);    
    }
    return invisible;
}
```

Comment: nice tip! could be usefull in the future! Thanks!

Comment: could you sovle your initial problem ? could you make it work in any other way? (I am also looking for some better way to do ;)